# Can we add specific product size to a different category?

Tags: magento-1.9

Can we add specific product size to a different category?

For example if product a (sizes--s,m,l) is in category a. but I want only product a (size--l) in category b.

Comment: http://www.proxiblue.com.au/premium-modules/magento-dynamic-category-products.html

Answer (score 0):

you can add them, but they might not work, since it depends on their visibility. if you're using configurable products, thus having simple products that define the sizes (s,m,l), if the simple products are set to visibility: nowhere, they won't show up in the catalog.

in other words, you can make the simple products show up in multiple categories, as long as they are visible in catalog. however, the main product (the configurable) will show up where you instruct it to show up (category 1 ... category n) but it will look the same across all categories (it will show the same options - s m l)